# how to show arabic alert from left to right

Tags: javascript

How to show java script alert of arabic characters/text from ltr(Left to right) format.In html we have ltr tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely operating system dependent.  Simply reversing the string is not 100% correct, since this does not render punctuation correctly.

If you need 100% locale independence in the browser, I would suggest using an HTML dialog, like jQuery UI, instead of `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using the regular javascript alert()

however, you can use some custom javascript alert box (you can use HTML inside it)

some like this http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/ or http://jdstiles.com/java/jsalert.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi, this is possible using unicode control characters:
- variable 'g' without ucc

```
var g="أكتب تعليقا!\nWrite a comment!\n";
```

- variable 'g' with ucc

```
var g="‫أكتب تعليقا!\n‪Write a comment!\n";
```

or

```
var g="&#8235;أكتب تعليقا!\n&#8234;Write a comment!\n";
```

simply:
place (LRE) character (‪‪&#8234;) in multi-dir texts where embedded texts start from left-to-right;
place (RLE) character (&#8235;) in multi-dir texts where embedded texts start from right-to-left.

or on your win notepad right click where embedded text start, insert unicode..., (LRE) or (RLE)