# JavaScript Concat issue with Currency Symbol

Tags: javascript, arabic, right-to-left

I have to concat a numeric value with currency code, but the currency get append after the numeric value like **د.إ111**  but I want the currency to be appended in the front and then the price value

```
let price = 111;
let currency = "&#x62f;&#x2e;&#x625;";
let str3 =  currency.concat(price)
console.log(str3)
```

Comment: those symbols are arabic which is right to left.

Comment: Correct but I want that Arabic symbols in the front of the price value @DanielA.White

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162805/how-to-show-arabic-alert-from-left-to-right

Comment: Wouldn't this be better controlled by css?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it could but not for the `console.log`

Comment: https://harnerdesigns.com/blog/style-your-console-log-with-css/ you can style console output with css

Comment: @DanielA.White its not a duplicate . I tried with those examples but doesn't work

Comment: @evolutionxbox what if the OP is in node?

Comment: @DevNode I have a proposed solution below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the RTL code, the price will be on the RH and following by the currency name on the LH:

```js
let price    = 111;
let currency = "دإ";
let RTL      = "\u200F";
console.log(RTL +price + " " + currency);

// another method
let str3 = `${RTL}${price} ${currency}`;
console.log(str3);
```